# wso2carbon programmatically/configuration always consent

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to determine the proper way to configurer/modify an account created with WSO2 Carbon, such that the account will return authorization without the need for the user being prompted to explicitly consent.

The accounts are being created programmatically, and the "user" will never know or have the passwords, etc, so I just need the request of authorization to always generate and return a code without rerouting to the authenticate and/or consent pages.

I see that there is a PROMPT parameter that is part of the OAUTH standard, that can be set to NONE, but it says the user must be configured for "pre-configured consent"... so I guess what I am trying to figure out, is how do I set up these users, or identity server, or whatever it is I need to have PRE CONFIGURED CONSENT for the users I am creating?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `SkipUserConsent` set to `true` at `repository/conf/identity/identity.xml`.

***UPDATE***

The above will skip the consent page only. Since you need to skip the authentication page also, you can use [request path authentication](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Try+Request+Path+Authentication).

Comment: Thanks, will this skip authentication as well?

Comment: This will bypass the need for consent, but I also need to bypass authentication as well. Since the user has no way of ever knowing the username and password created for the account we will be using.

Comment: I didn't notice the need to skip authentication page, it can also be done. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I guess what I really need to do is probably set up user impersonation with a service account or something, but I just need to find the right documentation to do this... How to set up the key trusts etc, and have the OAUTH respond as if its the impersonated user etc..

Comment: I don't really understand the request path authentication page instructions, I am not playing with the playground... so how the heck to I fill in the values on the page referenced in step 8 etc???

I need to change the OAUTH, so I can change the reqeust path to auth bearer... and add create the oauthrequestpauthenticator, but when I click update, and go back to the page, it just shows basic-auth again... 

How do I deal with steps 8 and 9 when I am not dealing with the playground?

Comment: At request path config, you have to select oauthrequestpauthenticator from dropdown and click add button next to it before update. Then it should appear below the dropdown.

Comment: (Step 8 & 9) You just have to use the authorize endpoint to the value mentioned in doc at your oauth client. So ,from your client you should be sending a request like below
`https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?sectoken=<token>&scope=openid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<redirect_url>&client_id=<client_id>`

Comment: Let me read though this again, but I guess what I am missing is where is the sec token given/generated/shared or set up?  Changing my url to above when I want to authorize is simple enough, but when/where do I set up the shared key so that my sectoken is configured to be enough to bypass request for authentication?  Or is sectoken the same thing as client_secret?

Comment: When I click on ADD button It shows a path authenticator, but it never gives me any inputs to fill in

Comment: Okay, I got the basicauth working by setting the sectoken to the username:password base64 encoded, so that's nice, but I haven't yet figured out how to get the oauth request path authenticator to work yet.